# Android Studio clone Repository from git lab

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitlab

I now have tried to clone a repo from gitlab for serveral hours.

Linux ZorinOS, Android Studio 2021.2.1.4 (If it helps)

I have a gitlab account.
I greatet a ssh key (ssh-keygen -t rsa)
I added it to gitlab
Then I tried to clone it via ssh and url with this result:

```
            Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
            java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
            at git4idea.GitAppUtil.sendXmlRequest(GitAppUtil.java:30)
            at git4idea.http.GitAskPassApp.main(GitAskPassApp.java:58)
            Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

Then I start to google.
I enable "Use credential helper".
I create an access token in gitlab.
Tried the url methode again. Same error.
But the ssh methode gives a new one:

```
            git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
            Could not read from remote repository.
            Please make sure you have the correct access rights
            and the repository exists.
```

I let my teamleader check all my permissions, but I have all rights and permissions I can have. And both the ssh and url where directly copied from gitlab.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong and nothing seems to help. I've done these steps multiple times - nothing.

Pleases help me.

Comment: You seem to be using the IDEA IDE to clone (`git4idea.http.GitAsk....`), which probably adds its own wrinkles. (It's using [tag:jgit], not C Git.) Try command-line Git to see if that makes any significant difference. Meanwhile, to use ssh access, use `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` to see who GitLab *think* you are: this completely bypasses Git and lets you debug the problem before adding extra Git and/or IDE complications.

Comment: @torek ssh does not no who I am ... ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: ssh doesn't know *or care* who you are: it presents, to GitLab, a *key*. GitLab use the *key* to *figure out* who you are. (Think of the key as an electronic key card with an ID number on it. That ID number is your "employee number" or equivalent, they look it up and see who you are.) But if you're getting a `Temporary failure in name resolution` error, ssh is unable to reach GitLab in the first place and cannot present the key. This is a network issue on your host.

Answer (score 0):

> I enable "Use credential helper". I create an access token in gitlab.

That is a good idea, but only for HTTPS URL (`https://gitlab.com/me/myProject`), not SSH ones (`git@gitlab.com:me/myProject`)

So try and switch to HTTPS, to see if the project access issue persists.